# How to set UTF-8 properly in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8

I'm using Hibernate for a JEE solution. And I need to database connection to be UTF-8. Here're what I tried :

### Database side

```
mysql> select c.character_set_name from information_schema.tables as t, information_schema.collation_character_set_applicability as c where c.collation_name = t.table_collation and t.table_schema = "ir2016" and t.table_name = "personne";
+--------------------+
| character_set_name |
+--------------------+
| utf8               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I've also inserted example data from MySQL Workbench. Results are well encoded in UTF-8. So the problem must come from the JEE server side.

### JEE side

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--Databaseconnectionsettings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ir2016?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxxx</property>    
        <property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="connection.CharSet">utf8</property>

        <!--JDBC connectionpool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!--SQL dialect-->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!--EnableHibernate'sautomaticsession contextmanagement -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!--Disablethe second-levelcache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!--Echo all executedSQL to stdout-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="Quiz.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Proposition.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Question.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Personne.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Choisir.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**server.xml**

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

**JSP pages**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: so, what's the problem? can't you write to your db in utf-8?

Comment: Yes, the problem is I still can't write to db in utf8

Comment: The first output is probably irrelevant; instead, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE personne;`

Comment: "Can't write" means??  Server crashes?  Nothing happens?  Garbage is put into the table?  Exception?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JEE solution, so you need to check your `web.xml` whether it is configured to accept UTF-8 and I just forget about it. I need a filter to do it

**web.xml**

```
<filter> 
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>com.yourcompany.yourapp.util.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
  <init-param> 
    <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name> 
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 
  </init-param> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

**CharacterEncodingFilter.java**

```
package com.yourcompany.yourapp.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Struts 1.3.10 encoding problem
 * 
 * @see http://www.coderanch.com/t/557874/Struts/Struts-encoding
 */
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter { 
    private FilterConfig fc; 

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req; 
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp; 

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8"); 
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8"); 

        chain.doFilter(request, response); 

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8"); 
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Source: [Struts 1.3.10 encoding problem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/557874/Struts/Struts-encoding)